# How I can change colors Bubble map in Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I try to plot a bubble map, but I can't change the color of the bubbles and colorbar, any idea?

Here is my code:

```
# Libraries
import pandas as pd
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


# Set the dimension of the figure
my_dpi=96
plt.figure(figsize=(2600/my_dpi, 1800/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)

# read the data (on the web)
data = pd.read_csv("dengue_1990_2019.csv", sep=";")

# Make the background map
m=Basemap(llcrnrlon=-93, llcrnrlat=3,urcrnrlon=-52,urcrnrlat=28, resolution='h')
#m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#A6CAE0', linewidth=0)
m.fillcontinents(color='grey', alpha=0.3)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.1, color="white")
m.shadedrelief()

# Add a point per position

plt.scatter(data\['homelon'\], data\['homelat'\], data\['n'\]/5, cmap="coolwarm", alpha=0.4, edgecolors="grey", linewidth=2)

plt.colorbar(orientation='vertical',shrink = 0.5)
plt.title('Caribbean')
```

[image]

Comment: The parameters of [`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) are: `x`, `y`, `s`, `c`, ... In the code `s` is used to set the bubble size. `c` will be needed to set values for the colors. If c contains scalar values, they will be mapped using the `cmap` and the colorbar will show the approriate range.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example?

Comment: You could try `plt.scatter(data['homelon'], data['homelat'], s=data['n']/5, c=data['n'], cmap="coolwarm", ...)`. Or maybe another column from your dataframe.

Comment: Thanks again, now works!!